# How to include files using a pattern based on build configuration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a website with the following folder structure:

```
Solution
 -App
 -Extra
   -Folder1
   -Folder2
```

The assemblies created in Folder1 and Folder2 are not referenced by App so I have to add them when building for publishing:

So I did:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <_Files Include="..\Extra\**\Extra*.dll;..\Extra\**\Extra*.pdb" />
  <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_Files.Identity)">
    <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
  </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
</ItemGroup>
```

The above doesn't consider the build configuration. How and where should I use `$Configuration` so that that files included are taken from the correct bin folder?

Comment: you can use `Condition` property to make selection, but can you specify where you need to modify depending on `$Configuration`?

Comment: What's the structure of your Folder1 and Folder2?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Standard .NET project structure

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono You can just use the $(Configuration) in your script. It represents Debug during debug mode, and represents Release in Release mode. But i'm bit confused about `that files included are taken from the correct bin folder?`, I assume you mean the bin folder under Folder1 and Folder2? Hope I don't misunderstand :(

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Yes. Folder1 (& 2, etc) have this structure: `bin\Release\net471` or `bin\Debug\net471` depending on the build configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the actual structure for your solution should be:

```
Solution
 -App
 -Extra
   -Folder1
     -bin
       -Debug
       -Release
   -Folder2
     -bin
       -Debug
       -Release
```

Then the script could be something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <_Files Include="..\Extra\**\**\$(Configuration)\net471\Extra*.dll;..\Extra\**\**\$(Configuration)\net471\Extra*.pdb" />
  <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_Files.Identity)">
    <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
  </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
</ItemGroup>
```